# onMapReady start at current location (using getting started code from google))

Tags: android, google-maps

So this is complete starter code from google.  It defaults to Sydney.  How to I default it to current location?

I know I have to use `setlocationenabled(true)` but I don't know how to get the `LatLng`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
/*        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
*/
     //NEED TO SET MOVE CAMERA TO CURRENT LOCATION
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap can get your current location by using [`getMyLocation`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()). However, its now deprecated and the Google documentation suggest you use `FusedLocationProviderAPI`.

> This method is deprecated.
>
> use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or the [Location Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).